# Localisation in-app on Android, issue

Tags: applications, gps, vpn

I will try to be brief :
There is this app, a game (World of Warriors) that DO NOT ASK FOR PERMISSION TO TRACK LOCALISATION. In this same app, there is this offer, Tapjoy (in the app, not through the Tapjoy app), that asks you to check an ad, download an app, complete a survey etc, in exchange of some of the game currency. However, the offers change in function of where you are. French dont have the same as Italians that dont have the same as Americans etc ...
I tried to change my language, my localisation, the degree of localisation (only GPS, only network, both), using a fake gps provider, a VPN (Tunnelbear, Hola and a tons of others), but it doesnt change anything at all.
Do you have any idea of how this is working ? Again, the app does not ask for gps localisation !

Comment: Because greetings and taglines are superfluous, SE doesn't want them in posts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple IP location lookup.
There are some services that offer so called *IP2Country* lookup that gives you the country of an IP address. For instance http://www.iplocation.net/ combines multiple services and presents you all results of their respective databases.
All of them will *at least* share the same country (probably the one you are currently in) and mostly your rough region.

Comment: Hello GiantTree, and first of all thank you for your answer.
If i understand well, any app can know where i am and share this information without asking for permission ?
Is there any way to fake this IP on Android ?

Comment: You can use a VPN or Elite/Anonymous proxy to hide your IP, but apart from that your location is kind of public. Google offers such a service as well, but using the native methods require the permission *ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION*.

Comment: But as i said, i already used some VPN and it doesnt change rat ! That's why i was so surprised ... I still don't understand then.

Comment: Some VPNs don't tunnel all connections through themselves, but only the connections to specific hosts. Those are common in corporate VPN setups. Also it may be possible to get your public IP through Android.

Comment: Is there any solution then ? I'm willing to do anything to resolve this issue.